Initial RDP connection slow when using DNS name
I'm connecting to a computer on my home network via RDP, using mstsc.exe. The step "Securing remote connection..." takes a very long time if I connect to the computer using the DNS name to my home network.
Once connected, performance is fine.
If I manually look up the external IP and connect like that the connection is pretty much instant. The same if I first set up a VPN connection to the local network and connect to the local IP of the computer. And using the DNS name when the VPN is up is still slow to connect.
I've tried ipconfig /flushdns on both client and target computer, but it hasn't helped.
I tried connecting via the DNS name from a 2nd client computer at the same location as the 1st one and it does not have the long connection time, so I'm pretty convinced it's something local to the 1st client computer causing it.
Any suggestions I can try to speed up the connection process from the 1st client when using the DNS name?

Speeding up the process requires investigating what makes it so unusually slow in the first place. Is either of the client computers an Active Directory member? What VPN software are you using, and does the 1st client computer have any other VPN software installed? If you install Wireshark on clients and run a capture on the network interfaces, what kind of traffic does it show during connection attempt – is there any difference in DNS traffic between captures from the two client computers? Is there any unexpected traffic on UDP port 389 ("CLDAP"), or TCP/UDP port 88 (Kerberos)?

Is the "DNS name" a FQDN or something else such as a single-word local "short name"?

@grawity
Yes, 1st client is part of a corporate domain (it's my work laptop). I assume it's AD, we use MS tools etc.
The VPN software is OpenVPN Connect, since OpenVPN is the only VPN protocol that my somewhat aging Asus router supports. But perhaps I was unclear about this part; Having the VPN connection up or down doesn't change the behavior. Whenever I connect using the domain name, it's slow. When using an IP address - any IP address - it's fast.
Also tried it now actually from within the home network (VPN down) using the domain name and it's predictably slow to connect.

@grawity
I ran a capture on the 1st client. It quickly asks the DNS server for the IP and gets the reponse promptly. It check a bunch of other dns names as well while the waiting is going on, corporate stuff, Microsoft stuff, but I think this is probably due to other processes running on the system. I tried closing down as much as possible while capturing, but there's still a bunch of stuff I can't turn off, corporate stuff. :) Interestingly, it does check the dns name again, about halfway through the wait. Not sure what's up with that.

@grawity
(Capturing the same thing on a 2nd cient just showed the one DNS request and immediately after the connection was made.)
"udp.port eq 389" yielded no entries. Neither did "udp.port eq 88 or tcp.port eq 88". Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I'm not very experienced with Wireshark.

I can also add that while "Securing remote connection..." is going on, there's no noticeable indication on the target computer that the 1st client is about to connect. Read: The desktop isn't locked until the actual connection happens after the wait. This to me is another indication that the target computer has nothing to do with whatever is going on and that this problem only involves the 1st client computer.
Oh, and port 3389 is forwarded to the local IP of the target computer, but that maybe goes without saying.

@Swisstone
By DNS name I meant a domain name that I have registered for my home IP address, e.g. my.site.com that resolves to my external IP. Not an FQDN or a COMPUTER-NAME. Maybe there's a better term for this. :)

"A long time" is pretty vague.  But seeing this: Why is RDP so slow sometimes during "Securing remote connection" stage?, I would ask: Is it waiting for slightly more than  20 seconds?

@Luuk When I tested it yesterday it took slightly over a minute. Today when I tested it just now it took 58 seconds. So thereabout. When it works properly from another computer it takes less than a second.

You could try helping the DNS, but adding a line to your c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file like 192.168.1.2 my.site.com.  When that helps, your problem is caused by a DNS setting. (But I am not a systemadministrator, so canot help you with that)

@Luuk Good idea to at least try it, so I did, but unfortunately it had no effect. I tried a negative test first by purposely entering an incorrect IP address and then it's just says "Initiating remote connection..." for a short while, before timing out. With the correct IP I immediately get past this step and onto the password prompt, which would mean it has reached the target computer and communicated with it already. Actually opening the remote session was still slow though, like above. So it's the same behavior. But it was worth a shot all the same, so thanks for your suggestion!
